# How to make springboot register a RestController?

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I havent worked too much with Spring API tools before, have more experience with Jersey. I have looked at many different articles explaining how to get REST endpoints wired up with Springboot and I just dont see why this is not working.

Here are some relevant code snippets:

In application.properties

```
server.port=5000
```

The package is com.myproj

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.myproj"})
public class ClaimsIntakeServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClaimsIntakeServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

In com.myproj.controllers

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
public class ClaimController {


    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Item> read() {
        System.out.println("hi");
        return new ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

If i hit this URL in postman: https://localhost:5000/hello ..
It says

> connection refused

How do I wire up a rest endpoint with springboot so I can hit it with postman as shown above?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myproj"})
public class HelloWorldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {


@RequestMapping(path = "/hello-world", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public HelloWorldResponse getHelloWorld() {
        return new HelloWorldResponse("hello!!");
    }
}
```

Docs [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

Comment: Thanks. Have seen that and used as reference. Does not work. I feel like there is something wrong with wiring up the components. But I've tried all sorts of recommended ways similar to ComponentScan

Answer (score 0):

For some reason while i get all the stuff for API with this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-cosmosdb-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I had to include this as well in order for the API to work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: ok was just a dependency problem, glad you solved it